# Spyder Ipython: pop up of function arguments after '"(" for functions of inherited cython class

Tags: python, arguments, ipython, cython, spyder

How can I modify my cython class or my ipython settings and spyder settings, so that, while working in ipython and in the editor, the function arguments are displayed automatically?
I have written a class in cython (cyclass, with cdef class) which is inherited to another python class (pyclass). Now, in workspace I have a pyclass object and want to  access the cyclass functions with automated argument pop up. Is this possible?
I'm glad for any help, thank you

Comment: Is this of any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668252/cython-cdef-class-not-displaying-doc-string-or-init-parameters? I'm not convinced it's quite the same, but it might be partly what IPython and Spyder use to build this information (maybe)

Comment: @DavidW thanks for your reply. I compiled with setting the 'embedsignature' directive to True but it has no effect on my issue